# Can I use windows 7 disc for windows xp recovery?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp

I need to follow [these](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307545)

```
md tmp
copy c:\windows\system32\config\system c:\windows\tmp\system.bak
copy c:\windows\system32\config\software c:\windows\tmp\software.bak
copy c:\windows\system32\config\sam c:\windows\tmp\sam.bak
copy c:\windows\system32\config\security c:\windows\tmp\security.bak
copy c:\windows\system32\config\default c:\windows\tmp\default.bak

delete c:\windows\system32\config\system
delete c:\windows\system32\config\software
delete c:\windows\system32\config\sam
delete c:\windows\system32\config\security
delete c:\windows\system32\config\default

copy c:\windows\repair\system c:\windows\system32\config\system
copy c:\windows\repair\software c:\windows\system32\config\software
copy c:\windows\repair\sam c:\windows\system32\config\sam
copy c:\windows\repair\security c:\windows\system32\config\security
copy c:\windows\repair\default c:\windows\system32\config\default
```

steps to fix a problem I'm having on an XP machine. I only have a Windows 7 32 bit disc. Would there be any reason why I **shouldn't** do this and go find an XP disc instead?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problem at all with doing this. Those are just simple DOS commands to backup the corrupted registry files and then overwrite with good copies from the windows\repair folder. The XP bootloader should not be affected unless you mistakenly run fixboot, fixmbr and the like from Win7's Recovery Environment. If you want to use a GUI instead, you can also do this using a Linux LiveCD/USB.